# Wanting code to read and apply information from cmd line

Tags: java, cmd

I am making a program which calculates the amount of distance a car can drive  considering the MPG (constant) and how much gas is in the tank.

The following is my current code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Car {

    static double milesTraveled = 0; // miles until empty - tank initially empty
    static double gallonsOfGas = 0; // amount of fuel left in tank - initially empty
    static final double MPG = 25; // Miles per Gallon - Constant
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;

// Constructor One
    public Car() {
// ***Code for your constructor goes here***
        //make = "No Make";
        //model = "No Model";
        //year = 1965;

    }

// Constructor Part Two
    public Car(String[] args) {
        // ***Code for your constructor goes here***
          make = args[1];
          model = args[2];
          year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    }

// -------------------- Get User-entered Input ------------------
    public double initializeCar() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        gallonsOfGas = getInput();

        return gallonsOfGas*MPG;


    } // End of initializeCar

    public void displayCarInfo() {
        // ***Code for your method goes here***
        System.out.println("Make:  " + make);
        System.out.println("Model: " + model);
        System.out.println("Year:  " + year);
        System.out.println("MPG:   " + MPG);
    }

    public double getDistanceToEmpty(double gallon) {
        // ***Code for your method goes here***
        return gallon;
    }

    public double getInput() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // create a Scanner object
        System.out.print("How many gallons do you have left in the tank?" + " <enter 0 if empty>: ");
        // ***Code for your method goes here***
        while (true) {
            if (gallonsOfGas >= 0 && gallonsOfGas <= 25) {
                gallonsOfGas = in.nextDouble();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("How many gallons do you have left in the tank?" + " <enter 0 if empty>: ");
            }
            
        }
        return gallonsOfGas;

    }
} // end class
```

where the comment says Constructor 2, is where i was supposed to make this information read from the cmd line. Currently, i am getting this output when i run the program.

```
C:\Users\Andrew\eclipse-workspace\Lab6\src>java Lab6 1965 Ford Mustang 

Make:  null
Model: null
Year:  0
MPG:   25.0
How many gallons do you have left in the tank? <enter 0 if empty>: 5
How many gallons do you have left in the tank? <enter 0 if empty>: 5

The Car can go 125.0 miles before it runs out of gas
```

currently, none of the 3 are being updated. I honestly have no idea how wrong i am doing this, since it is my first time i need the cmd line for the code to function properly but im sure my faulty code is either in this section:

```
public Car(String[] args) {
        // ***Code for your constructor goes here***
          make = args[1];
          model = args[2];
          year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    }
```

or this section

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Car myCar=new Car();
        myCar.displayCarInfo();
        //System.out.print("Enter number of gallons car have in tank: ");
        myCar.initializeCar();
        double gallons = myCar.initializeCar();
     
 
        // ----------------------- Display the Car info ------------------------------
        // ***Your code goes here***
        System.out.println("\nThe Car can go "+myCar.getDistanceToEmpty(gallons)+" miles before it runs out of gas");
}
```

While i am not looking for straight up code, any help/ tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer but then deleted it, so i'll put the answer here.

```
Car myCar=new Car();
```

shouldve been

```
Car myCar=new Car(args);
```

Comment: ? that must have been a mistake because it did, i was in the middle of replying to you saying it did when it said the  comment had been deleted. If i did, i am sorry about that.